# How to add "Like" button to a facebook page's iframe app tab?

Tags: facebook, iframe, button

I created an iframe tab app which pulls hot photos from my facebook page's wall. Here is my app: http://www.facebook.com/pages/Gadgets-Girls/227053027308839?sk=app_146407465433194

I want to add a like button to every pic, so people can like the pics in the app tab and don't need to go to the wall. How can i do this? I tried the regular way, but got warned:The page at {address} could not be reached.

The problem is how can I add like button to facebook page's photos? How to link like button to such address http://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=227099727304169&set=a.227058580641617.78517.227053027308839&type=1?